# How to make links like the one in CommentPress?

Tags: html

If you check the websites which use commentpress for commenting (example: http://futureofthebook.org/commentpress/), you can see there is a link like:

2 comments on paragarph 1

and when you click on the link, it will show the comments for that paragraph, and if you click on the link again, the comments will hide.

How can I make those kind of link? I know if use something like:

```
  <a href="#commenting">Comment for whole article<br></a>
```

I will have a link, that if I click on it, it will take me to the another part of the page, but I want to have the same thing as I mentioned above.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the page source to see how that site did it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find what you were referring to on that web site, but it sounds like you're describing some method of toggling visibility of an element.  You can do that with either JavaScript or with CSS selectors; [here's how to do it with CSS](http://www.reddit.com/r/css/comments/1f1nmm/is_it_possible_to_toggle_div_visibility_with_css/).

Comment: In the right column of the page, you can see it is mentioned like: 5 Comments on the whole Page    5 Commetns on Paragraph1 ... , If you click on the link you can see what I mean